# How can I manage files with Git that don't reside in my local git folder?

Tags: git, shell

I have multiple shell scripts and config files which I frequently amend and want to re-use on multiple hosts. So I want to use Github to keep a repository from where I can push updated versions and later pull the latest versions from all hosts.

Git seems an easy solution as I also have an external backup of all my files.

The only thing naggin me is that git only manages repositories under the folder git while all my files are spread out across many folders on a server. How can I use git on files that I dont want to copy into the git folder?

I tried copying files in and out of the git folder but that is a waste of time. I just want to push/pull once I have amended a script.

Comment: Symlink the "real" files to the the git-controlled files in the repo folder.